# Gridview scrolling images not working smoothly in android

Tags: android, gridview, scrollview

Hi in the below displaying all the images into gridview.gridview images displaying correctly.default gridview will give scroll option,Now Scrolling images it's not scrolling smoothly.

Can any one help me .how to scroll smoothly all the images like normal scrolling.this is my below code any where i did mistake please help me

**java**

```
public class GridFragment2 extends Fragment {

    private static final String TAG = GridFragment.class.getSimpleName();
public static boolean isSelectedGrid2;
    private GridView mGridView;
    private ProgressBar mProgressBar;

    private GridViewAdapter2 mGridAdapter;
    private ArrayList<GridItem> mGridData;
    private String FEED_URL = "http://javatechig.com/?json=get_recent_posts&count=45", searchKey;
    String vv;
    LinearLayout top;
    View hr;

    String catid;



    SharedPreferences imgSh;
    SharedPreferences p, got;



    public GridFragment2() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_gridview2, container, false);

        mGridView = (GridView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.gridView);
        mProgressBar = (ProgressBar)rootView.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        top = (LinearLayout)rootView.findViewById(R.id.top);
        hr = rootView.findViewById(R.id.hr);
        top.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        hr.setVisibility(View.GONE);



        imgSh = this.getActivity().getSharedPreferences("data", Context.MODE_APPEND);
        p = this.getActivity().getSharedPreferences("gridData", Context.MODE_APPEND);
        got = this.getActivity().getSharedPreferences("gotData", Context.MODE_APPEND);

        //Initialize with empty data
        mGridData = new ArrayList<>();
        mGridAdapter = new GridViewAdapter2(rootView.getContext(), R.layout.grid_item_layout2, mGridData);
        mGridView.setAdapter(mGridAdapter);

        //Grid view click event
        mGridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
                //Get item at position
                isSelectedGrid2=true;
                String catalogueID = p.getString("SelectedCatalogueIdFromGrid1", "");
                GridItem item = (GridItem) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), ImageGallery.class);
                ImageView imageView = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.grid_item_image);
                int[] screenLocation = new int[2];
                imageView.getLocationOnScreen(screenLocation);
                SharedPreferences prefPosition=getActivity().getSharedPreferences("positionPref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                SharedPreferences.Editor positionEditor=prefPosition.edit();
                positionEditor.putInt("position", position);
                positionEditor.commit();
                //Pass the image title and url to DetailsActivity
                intent.putExtra("left", screenLocation[0]).
                        putExtra("top", screenLocation[1]).
                        putExtra("width", imageView.getWidth()).
                        putExtra("height", imageView.getHeight()).
                        putExtra("title", item.getTitle()).
                        putExtra("image", item.getImage()).
                        putExtra("catid", catalogueID).putExtra("position",position);

                //   Log.d("image", (item.getImage()).toString());

                //Start details activity
                getActivity().finish();
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        //Start download
        new AsyncHttpTask().execute(FEED_URL);
        mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        return rootView;
    }



    //Downloading data asynchronously
    public class AsyncHttpTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Integer> {

        @Override
        protected Integer doInBackground(String... params) {
            Integer result = 1;

            parseResult();

            return result;

        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {
            // Download complete. Lets update UI

            if (result == 1) {
                mGridAdapter.setGridData(mGridData);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getBaseContext(), "Failed to fetch data!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            //Hide progressbar
            mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }


    String streamToString(InputStream stream) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));
        String line;
        String result = "";
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            result += line;
        }

        // Close stream
        if (null != stream) {
            stream.close();
        }
        return result;
    }


    private void parseResult() {


        catid = p.getString("SelectedCatalogueIdFromGrid1", "");
        int clickedPosn = p.getInt("clickedPosition", 0);
        int count = p.getInt("numOfImagesInside"+catid+clickedPosn, 0);

        Log.d("counterman-id", String.valueOf(count));

        GridItem item;
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {

            item = new GridItem();

            item.setTitle("");
            // item.setImage("file://" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + "thumbImage" + catid + i + ".jpg");
            item.setImage("/data/data/com.example.adaptiz.tanishq/"+"thumbImage" + catid + i+".jpg");
            // item.setImage(imgSh.getString("thumb" + i, ""));
            mGridData.add(item);
        }

    }
```

**Adapter**

```
public class GridViewAdapter2 extends ArrayAdapter<GridItem> {

    //private final ColorMatrixColorFilter grayscaleFilter;
    private Context mContext;
    private int layoutResourceId;
    private ArrayList<GridItem> mGridData = new ArrayList<GridItem>();

    public GridViewAdapter2(Context mContext, int layoutResourceId, ArrayList<GridItem> mGridData) {
        super(mContext, layoutResourceId, mGridData);
        this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.mGridData = mGridData;
    }


    /**
     * Updates grid data and refresh grid items.
     *
     * @param mGridData
     */
    public void setGridData(ArrayList<GridItem> mGridData) {
        this.mGridData = mGridData;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;
        ViewHolder holder;



        if (row == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) mContext).getLayoutInflater();
            row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);
            Typeface type_normal = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "HelveticaNeue-Light.otf");

            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.titleTextView = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.grid_item_title);
            holder.titleTextView.setTypeface(type_normal);

            holder.download=(ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.img);

            holder.imageView = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.grid_item_image);
            row.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) row.getTag();
        }

        GridItem item = mGridData.get(position);

        holder.titleTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(item.getTitle()));


        File image = new File(item.getImage(), "");
        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inTempStorage = new byte[16*1024];
        options.inPurgeable = true;
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(image.getAbsolutePath(), options);
        // bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 230, 230, true);
        Log.d("the bitmap size", String.valueOf(bitmap.getWidth() + " " + bitmap.getHeight()));
        holder.imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        //bitmap=null;

        // Picasso.with(mContext).load(item.getImage()).into(holder.imageView);
        return row;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        TextView titleTextView;
        ImageView imageView;
        ImageView download;
    }
```

**xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/toprel"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:id="@+id/top"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:id="@+id/searchTitle"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:text="Search"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/leftTitle"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/leftTitle" />

        <EditText
            android:inputType="text"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:id="@+id/searchBox"
            android:background="@drawable/searchbg2x"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/searchTitle"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/searchTitle"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:imeOptions="actionSearch"



            />


    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:id="@+id/hr"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:layout_below="@id/top"
        />



    <GridView
        android:layout_below="@+id/hr"
        android:id="@+id/gridView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:columnWidth="200dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:numColumns="4"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:verticalSpacing="5dp"
        android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:fastScrollEnabled="true"/>

    <ProgressBar
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:visibility="gone"/>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/userlayout"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/gridView"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/gridView"

        >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:id="@+id/userView"
            android:text="username"

            />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/icon"
            />

    </LinearLayout>



    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=""
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/gridView"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

For that you have to use Image Loader to load image.

Refer below link for that.

http://www.androidhive.info/2012/07/android-loading-image-from-url-http/